# NoSuchMethodError using Ant

Tags: android, ant

I am new to Android.
I create a HelloAndroid Project using command-line(not Eclipse). /*Runs in Eclipse*/
Then I used Ant to build my HelloAndroid Project.
But while building it showed me the below output.

```
-resource-src:
     [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...

-aidl:
     [echo] Compiling aidl files into Java classes...

BUILD FAILED
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet.iterator()Ljava/
util/Iterator;

Total time: 1 second
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of `ant` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on this.

It was happened because of ant/JAVA_HOME paths.
SO I removed all java and ant paths and recreate them.
Now its working greatly.

Thkns